# How can I link a user to a specific leaderboard in the Game Center?

Tags: ios, ios7, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have set up my leader board in the **Game Center**.

How do I make it so when the user clicks the high score button, it takes them right to the specific leader board in the Game Center?

Is there a way to do it without using a specific link in a **UIWebView**?

I would prefer the Game Center to open outside of the app. My app is tailored for **iOS7** and above.

Answer (score 1):

Far far ago, under `iOS7`, U can't control what's happening inside the `GKGameCenterViewController`, just this 3 options:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GKGameCenterViewControllerState) {
    GKGameCenterViewControllerStateDefault = -1,
    GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards,
    GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements,
    GKGameCenterViewControllerStateChallenges,
};
```

U can set this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)   GKGameCenterViewControllerState viewState;
```

Like this (an example):

```
- (void)presentLeaderboardsOnViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    GKGameCenterViewController *leaderboardViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    leaderboardViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    leaderboardViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    [viewController presentViewController:leaderboardViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

From `iOS7` and above u have this property (never try it):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString *leaderboardIdentifier __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING( __MAC_NA, __IPHONE_7_0); // Showing specified leaderboard
```

So just set this property, and there u go, u have opened the `GKGameCenterViewController` with your wanted Leaderboard :)

Good luck!

**Edit:**

To dismiss the Game Center screen, in your `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` add this method:

```
- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController {
    [gameCenterViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still a bit confused. I know you said the - (void)presentLeaderboardsOnViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController was for under iOS7 but I tried it and it opened the leaderboard that I wanted it to. However when I went to click the "Done" button, it does not take me back to the app. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *leaderboardIdentifier Is the property that available from iOS7 and above. Now, for your question, see my next edit in my answer..